# efficient or muddy use of function calls

Tags: python, function, collatz

I am doing an exercise from a book that asks me to perform the Collatz sequence

> The Collatz conjecture is a conjecture in mathematics that concerns a sequence defined as follows: start with any positive integer n. Then each term is obtained from the previous term as follows: if the previous term is even, the next term is one half of the previous term. If the previous term is odd, the next term is 3 times the previous term plus 1. The conjecture is that no matter what value of n, the sequence will always reach 1.

and print the results.

I also, for my sake, wanted to record the number of iterations it would take before reaching 1 and save all the results along the way in a list.

What follows is the code I wrote. You can judge from the assignment that I'm a novice as this is probably fairly elementary work. My program works and provides the output exactly as I would like it. What I would like to know is: was this a good use of functions to achieve my goal or are the parameters/arguments needlessly complex?

```
def collatz(number):
    
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = number // 2
        return number

    else:
        number = (3*number + 1)
        return number


def try_again(a, clist, iterations):
    new_result = collatz(a)
    condition(new_result, clist, iterations)


def condition(a, clist, iterations):
    clist.append(a)
    if a == 1:
        finished(iterations, clist)
    else:
        iterations += 1
        try_again(a, clist, iterations)


def finished(iterations, clist):
    print(f"finished after {iterations} iterations")
    print(clist)

def main():
    clist = []
    number = int(input("Collatz seed: "))    
    a = collatz(number)
    condition(a, clist, iterations = 1) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: By "muddy" do you mean inefficient?

Comment: You might try for better responses at https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/